# Unity - Running A Pathfinding Algorithm on A Seperate Thread

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, coroutine

I have implemented a A* pathfinding algorithm into my Unity 2D game. Everything works but it can cause hickups when searching a broad map.

The problem is caused by a While-Loop being executed on the main thread. I want the algorithm to be able to run on a seperate thread to stop the game from feezing when the function runs.

My understanding of coroutines is that they are better to use for sequential functions, not heavy calculations like this. The function has to return a value or use references to attach a value.

How do I implement this CPU-heavy calculation without blocking the main thread? I.e. multithread?

**EDIT:**

Current implementation of Coroutines as pointed out by Heisenbug.

Uncomplete extraction from the "heavy calculation function" that should be spread out during a number of frames to even workloads.

```
//if the daemon is currently searching
public bool Searching;

//Create list for the algorithm
Pathfinding_Path Path = new Pathfinding_Path();
List<Pathfinding_Point> OpenList = new List<Pathfinding_Point>();
List<Pathfinding_Point> ClosedList = new List<Pathfinding_Point>();

//Agent is the object that shall pathfind, position is goal, callback
public IEnumerator Pathfind(GameObject Agent, Vector3 Position, Func<Pathfinding_Path,Vector3, bool,bool> Callback)
{
    //Abort if already searching
    if (Searching)
        yield break;

    Searching = true;

    //If the target position is not clear, abort
    if (!IsClear(Position))
    {
        Searching = false;
        yield break;
    }

    //Get the size of the agent
    Vector3 AgentSize = GetSize(Agent);

    //Start the algorithm
    Pathfinding_Point start = CreatePoint(AgentSize, Agent.transform.position, Position, 0);
    //Get possible steps from the first position
    CreateAdjacent(start, Position);
    //Add the node to the search tree
    OpenList.Add(start);

    //Keep track of how many iterations the function has ran (to not keep on going forever)
    int iterations = 0;

    //If there is an object to visit and the number of iterations is allowed
    while (OpenList.Count > 0 && iterations < 250)
    {
        iterations++;

        //Get the best node and visit it
        Pathfinding_Point point = GetBest(OpenList);
        OpenList.Remove(point);
        ClosedList.Add(point);    

        //Add all neighbors to the search tree
        foreach (Pathfinding_Point adjacent in point.Adjacent)
        {
            if (!ClosedList.Contains(adjacent))
            {
                if (!OpenList.Contains(adjacent))
                {
                    adjacent.Parent = point;


                    //The goal position is near, this is goal
                    if (Vector3.Distance(adjacent.Position, Position) <= AgentSize.sqrMagnitude * 0.5f)
                    {
                        //Add the final point to the path
                        Path.Add(adjacent);

                        //Get the last point
                        Pathfinding_Point step = Path.Points[0];
                        //Track backwards to find path
                        while(step.Parent != null){
                            Path.Add(step.Parent);
                            step = step.Parent;
                        }

                        Path.Finalize();

                        //Return the final path somehow (preferably using a callback method)
                        Callback(Path, Position, false);
                        Searching = false;
                        //Don't run the function no more
                        yield break;
                    } 
                    else if (IsClear(adjacent))
                    {
                        //Add to search tree
                        CreateAdjacent(adjacent, Position);
                        OpenList.Add(adjacent);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //If the score is lower this way, re-calculate it
                    if (point.G + 1 < adjacent.G)
                    {
                        adjacent.G = point.G + 1;
                        adjacent.F = adjacent.G + adjacent.H;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //If there are no more ways to go
    if(OpenList.Count == 0)
        yield break;

    //Here, the search has exceeded its limit on 250 iterations and shall continue after a small delay
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.005f);
    //The callback will run this function again, until the goal is reached or if there are no more nodes to visit
    Callback(Path, Position, true);
}
```

The callback that should handle the different cases which the search function might reach

```
//Path to use if it succeded, position that was the initial target, if the search is not yet finished and should be continued
bool GetPath(Pathfinding_Path Path, Vector3 pz, bool Continue)
{
    //Run the function again with the same parameters as the first time
    if (Continue)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Pathfinder.Pathfind(gameObject, pz, GetPath));
    }
    else if (Path.Points.Count > 0)
    {
        //A path has been found
        InvestigatePath = Path;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not to familiar with unity and if you can use the `Task` class, but if you can take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see how you can use `Task.Run()`. If you cannot use the `Task` class, [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/357033/unity3d-and-c-coroutines-vs-threading.html) is a question on the Unity forum that goes over a method for using the `System.Threading.Thread` class.

Comment: how are we supposed to help here if you don't post your code? It's never as simple as "put all your code in a coroutine, done".

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Sorry for not being clear enough. There is no real code involved in this question. I want to know how to do multithreading in unity, asynchronous functions or whatever you prefer. I could give you the code but it would only be clutter, since it adds nothin to the question.

Comment: Is your A* routine very dependent on Unity objects? I'd pessimistically guess not so much of Unity's methods/objects are thread-safe, so if you can separate its variables/logic from Unity's main thread, this basically becomes a very simple C# question (and C# has many helpful tools for multithreading)

Comment: @Katana314 You are correct that there is no thread-safety. I do use Unity Physics functions which I guess go under the "unity objects" category.

Comment: @Alex If it's worth the effort, you could find a way of extracting all basic data you need from Unity.Physics to some simpler interface. I'm guessing you'd basically need to copy out geometry data of your entire level, so maybe at that point you might have to give up. I guess this is why gamers are advised not to bother getting 8-core processors; the engines are still catching up.

Comment: @Katana314 Yeah, and I'm that process I will still have to loop - freezing the engine. Oh well. I guess I have to look for other ways

Comment: i'm afraid "how to do multithreading in unity" would be too broad as a question for this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could eventually use [threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as usual in C#. The point is that is not a convenient solution because you need to keep synchronized your thread with the engine loop. This might not be trivial.

> My understanding of coroutines is that they are better to use for
>   sequential functions, not heavy calculations like this.

This is not true. One of the main goals of coroutines (they are just [iterator blocks](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx)) is to spread computation over time (multiple-frames) in order to avoid hiccups. It's a form of cooperative multi-tasking so you'll get almost all benefits of threading without the complication of synchronization, because coroutines [will be executed](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) just after the main loop [Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) for scripts is completed.

Using coroutines you are responsible for how much computation will be executed each frame, so it's up to you organize your code to maintain a stable frame rate. In the case of pathfinding could be something like that:

```
IEnumerator PathFinding()
{
  while(!goalNodeReached)
  {
    VisitMaxNodes(maxNodesToVisit); // this function visit only a subset of the graph each frame
    yield return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: How exactly would I split the function up?
I've implemented a callback parameter that takes care of handling whether or not the search function should be ran again or if the final path has been found. After searching for a fixed number of nodes, I tell the callback method that it should run the search again. But how would I tell it to wait before doing so? Do I yield return waitforseconds before calling the callback method?

Comment: @Alex: it's impossible to answer without seeing the code. Mine was just an hint to use coroutine instead of thread. I slightly change the example to be more clear. yielding null will cause the coroutine to be interrupted and resumed the next frame.

Comment: The question has been updated to show the current implementation.

Comment: @Alex: from a quick look at your code, it seems that you are doing ad path finding search for a max depth of 250 in a single frame and if it fails you run it again after waiting (and you still will end up with no solution this way). Instead of re-running the search, I guess the way of spread the computation over multiple frames is to yield after a given number of iterations inside the main while loop.

Comment: that seems to work. But the fact that I yield return waitforseconds still freezes up the main thread for the number of seconds I tell it to, which is in turn quite understandable. How can I wait for a while without freezing it?

Comment: It shouldn't. waitforseconds will cause your routine not to be updated for the specified amount of time. other routines and the game it self will run normally.

Comment: alright. That probably means that I will have to lower the iteration count even further. Thanks for your help, I will accept this answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able spawn a new thread in the customary fashion and perform your calculation as long as the new thread doesn't have to interact with Unity itself, there are quite a few ways this could be accomplished but it's hard to say which one to use.  The last time I used it Unity didn't support some of the .NET 4.0 language features like Tasks but this might have changed.